# React errors after git clone and node modules install?

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I cloned my git repo so I can work on my other desktop. After clone, I ran npm install on both the root folder and frontend folder (MERN project) and checked the package.json for anything missing.

I think everything installed but when I start up my frontend server, I get React errors. The first was a syntax error even though the code is perfectly fine and working on my other computer.

Now I'm getting Line 12-21 "React" must be in scope when using JSX on my App.js below:

```
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom'
import Header from './components/Header'
import Footer from './components/Footer'
import HomeScreen from './screens/HomeScreen'
import ProductScreen from './screens/ProductScreen'
import CartScreen from './screens/CartScreen'
import CheckoutScreen from './screens/CheckoutScreen'
import LoginScreen from './screens/LoginScreen'

function App() {
  return (
      <Router>
        <Header />
        <div className="main-content h-full min-h-screen flex" style={{backgroundColor: '#f5fcf7'}}>
          <Route path="/" component={HomeScreen} exact />
          <Route path="/products/:id" component={ProductScreen}  />
          <Route path="/cart" component={CartScreen} />
          <Route path="/checkout" component={CheckoutScreen} />
          <Route path="/login" component={LoginScreen} />
        </div>
        <Footer />
      </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I know I don't have import react from 'react' but I removed it all from my project as I understand you don't need to import anymore.
It's working fine on my laptop.

I am guessing something happened where the npm install didn't install the react version correctly or didn't install some part of it.

Here is the package.json for the frontend:

```
{
  "name": "frontend",
  "proxy": "http://127.0.0.1:5000",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@craco/craco": "^5.9.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.14.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.7",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.8.3",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.6.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.5",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.1",
    "react-scripts": "^1.1.5",
    "redux": "^4.1.1",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.9",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "web-vitals": "^1.1.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "craco start",
    "build": "craco build",
    "test": "craco test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^9.8.6",
    "postcss": "^7.0.36",
    "tailwindcss": "npm:@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat@^2.2.9"
  }
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Why do you think `I know I don't have import react from 'react' but I removed it all from my project as I understand you don't need to import anymore. It's working fine on my laptop.` ? Like why do you not need React in the scope anymore? Cuz simply put , you do.

Comment: Newest version of react doesn't require importing react. Adding React makes no difference in fixing this problem unfortunately. The same code on my other computer is running fine.

Comment: Confirm react version .

Comment: Assuming your package.json files are the same on both machines, what about package.json.lock? Are they the same?

Comment: Package.json and package.json.lock are the same. They came from the same clone repository. Checking react version is giving me the same one shown in package.json. I'm not sure what's going on but I may just delete everything and start importing from scratch

Answer (score -1):

When you have a piece of "JSX" syntax within a file, you need to import React from "react" for it to work, so all you need to do is the following (please note the first line):

```
import React from 'react'; //<-- add this line
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom'
import Header from './components/Header'
import Footer from './components/Footer'
import HomeScreen from './screens/HomeScreen'
import ProductScreen from './screens/ProductScreen'
import CartScreen from './screens/CartScreen'
import CheckoutScreen from './screens/CheckoutScreen'
import LoginScreen from './screens/LoginScreen'

function App() {
  return (
      <Router>
        <Header />
        <div className="main-content h-full min-h-screen flex" style={{backgroundColor: '#f5fcf7'}}>
          <Route path="/" component={HomeScreen} exact />
          <Route path="/products/:id" component={ProductScreen}  />
          <Route path="/cart" component={CartScreen} />
          <Route path="/checkout" component={CheckoutScreen} />
          <Route path="/login" component={LoginScreen} />
        </div>
        <Footer />
      </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

However, you may not need to do this in future versions of react.

Comment: You don't need that anymore. And he knows that. https://reactjs.org/blog/2020/09/22/introducing-the-new-jsx-transform.html

Comment: i'm aware of this, see the OP, he literally said the error was "React" must be in scope when using JSX" *_*

Comment: The question is, why that error happens when he is using React 17+ and while the same code works on another machine !!